# How to use "Right" and "Find" function to extract data in a cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in a cell D2 like this:

1234 West King Street
P.O. Box 123
Carson City, NV 12345

I know if I want to extract zipcode the formula should be:

`=RIGHT(D2,FIND(" ",D2,FIND(" ",D2)+1)-4)`

Now I want to extract the city information in the cell, what's the formula?

Comment: Does the city always have two names?  Do you have a list of the cities that you want to find?  It is not possible to have excel reliably pull the city without a set rule.  The best is to have a list of the cities and compare those to the address and return the correct match.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thanks Scott for the quick response. Unfortunately they do not always have two names. The only thing is that they have a comma after city name as a separator, but there is no separator before city name.

Comment: Do you have a complete list of possible cities ???

Comment: Then without a list of city names, this is not possible within Excel.  There is no reliable method that will be able to parse what is part of the street address and what is part of the city name.

Comment: @ScottCraner@Gary's Student  How about this. All cities in my sheet are in Nevada. I think I could pull a list of all city names in Nevada. If I have the list, what can I do with Excel Formula?

Comment: The real question is: why is all that information just inside one cell? It would make more sense having different cells: one for postal code, one for city name, ...

Comment: Is there always a number just before the city name?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming zipcode is always 5 digits from the end, your city name always start from [1] the end of 2nd number (and a space), and ends at [2] the comma before the "NV".

Then you may use `=find()` function that look for [1]&[2] then use `=mid()` extract all the text in between. I mean : `=mid(d2,find([1]),find([2]))`

full formula :

```
=MID(D2, IF(MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))=MIN(IFERROR(FIND("0",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),LEN(D2))),MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0)),MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0)))+2, FIND(", NV ",D2)-IF(MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))=MIN(IFERROR(FIND("0",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),LEN(D2)),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),LEN(D2))),MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2,MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0))+1),0)),MAX(IFERROR(FIND("0 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("1 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("2 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("3 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("4 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("5 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("6 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("7 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("8 ",D2),0),IFERROR(FIND("9 ",D2),0)))-2)
```

---

Extra  :

> if I want to extract zipcode

then you should just use `=right(D2,5)` | Your original formula seems to be looking for the 1st and 2nd " " (space) from the left, not from the right.. using the right() formula doesn't ma

> a list of all city names in Nevada

you can get it via wolframalpha.com with "Nevada cities" as the input.